# Size of $\Omega$ to have independent +1/-1 random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I know we rarely want to describe $\Omega$ itself when doing probability, but just being curious:

Let $(X_i)_{1 \leq 1 \leq n}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables such that $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1) = 1/2$.

If $\Omega = \{ \omega_1,  \omega_2 \}$ then it's impossible to have $n=2$ such independent random variables: $P(X_1 = 1) \times P(X_2 = 1)= 1/4$ cannot be equal to $P(X_1 = 1 \cap X_2 = 1)$ because no event has probability $1/4$ in $\Omega$.

Question: Is it true in general that $\Omega$ should have at least something like $2^n$ elements, to allow that a sequence $(X_i)_{1 \leq 1 \leq n}$ of **i.i.d.** random variables such that $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1) = 1/2$ exist?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that as soon as you start multiplying probabilities:$$ P(X_1 = 1) \times P(X_2=1),$$
you're no longer in $\Omega$ but in $\Omega\times\Omega$ so that you have $\Omega_{new} = \{(1,1), (1,-1), (-1,1), (-1, -1)\}$. If we let $y$ any old variable, this changes the second statement to $$P(X_1 = (1,y) \cap X_2 = (y,1))$$
where $P(X_1|X_2) = 1/2$ and vice versa, which agrees with the previous values.

Comment: The couples you mention (a, b) are the values of $\omega \mapsto  (X_1(\omega), X_2 (\omega))$ but not necessarily the input probability space.